# Lubuntu - Screen looks broken after installing

Tags: lubuntu, screen

I'm new here.

I tried Lubuntu from the ISO and it was working ok, so I decided to install it. (USB ISO installation with Rufus).

After installation, some software/driver problem is causing the screen to look broken. 3/4 of the screen looks black.

Could someone give me a hint? thanks.

Image:

[Lubuntu screen looks broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33WUY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

i created this account just to tell that i had the same problem and managed to find a solution. the system that i am using is a Samsung NC10 netbook with a res of 1280x600

this is the solution. (please tell me if it also works on your computer!)

you need to edit /etc/default/grub

change this line of code

```
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

to this

```
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

and then use

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot

and the best part is, i got this solution by accident as well.

credits to this forum post at Ubuntu forums for this code.
[here's a link to the post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2260082)

And as always. have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Got the exact same problem. Funnily enough, running Live Lubuntu on boot displays the screen properly!

Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/38834 it worked for me! My screen resolution is a bit off but at least I have a proper GUI now.

Edit: after having no luck at all with the `nomodeset` trick and getting stuck with a 800x600 resolution in what should be 1024x600, the best solution was installing Lubuntu 16. All looks good now, apparently.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my Acer Aspire One netbook (Intel 945GME, 1024x600) on Lubuntu versions before 18.04, but installing 18.04 solved the issue.